# nginx redirect to hashbang URL without URL encoding

Tags: nginx

I have a rewrite rule that looks like the following

```
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /mysite/#!/$1/login;
```

The idea is that a shortcode like

```
/foo
```

gets redirected to

```
/mysite/#!/foo/login
```

However nginx is redirecting to:

```
/mysite/%23!/foo/login
```

How do I prevent the URL encoding from happening in the rewrite?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Testing both internal and external redirection, the `#` is not URL encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We're using nginx as a proxy to a Tomcat instance, if that makes any difference.  The encode URL is definitely coming from nginx. We can see it in the Tomcat access logs. URLs that already have a # pass through okay, so it definitely seems to be the rewrite rule causing it.

Comment: We ended up switching from a `rewrite` to a `return` and that solved our problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue by using a reverse proxy.

Nginx is actually doing the right thing, as `#` is a [reserved character for URIs](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc3986.pdf#25) and identifies the start of the [fragment identifier](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc2396.pdf#39).

The fragment identifier is for the browser's use only and is not usually received by the server in the requested URL. I am not sure how your Tomcat server is receiving requests containing a naked `#` in the first place.